# tex.hashtokens incomplete?

Tags: luatex, tex-core

This came up while trying to answer [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574563/longest-built-in-latex-command), and concerns [`tex.hashtokens()` in LuaTeX](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/luatex.pdf#page=206). Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\message{The meaning of (\string\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty) is (\meaning\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty)}

\directlua{
for i,v in pairs(tex.hashtokens()) do
   if v:find('beamertemplatenavigation') then
      print('found:', v)
   end
end
}

\message{The meaning of (\string\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty) is still (\meaning\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty)}

\end{document}
```

When run with `lualatex` on my system (“`This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)`”), this prints (with a newline I added for clarity):

```
The meaning of (\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty) is (macro:->\setbeamertemplate {navigation symbols}{})
found:  beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsvertical
found:  beamertemplatenavigationsymbolshorizontal
 The meaning of (\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty) is still (macro:->\setbeamertemplate {navigation symbols}{})
```

The macro `\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty` clearly exists, so why doesn't the Lua code find it? Have I misunderstood something?

I get similar results with MiKTeX 20.11.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Wow, surprising behaviour, and not mentioned in the documentation either! Could you post that as an answer? I think it completely answers the question. (Meanwhile thanks to that comment I'm now using the workaround of invoking the program as `hash_extra=0 lualatex foo.tex`, and it seems to show all entries now.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LuaTeX (as well as all other TeX versions derived from web2c after 1995) use a hash table separated into two parts: A normal hash table with up to `hash_size` (65536) entries and an additional part with `hash_extra` many entries (`hash_extra` can be set at runtime, TeXLive sets it to 600000 by default). (The `hash_extra` part is not really a hash table but more of a linear overflow list, but that's irrelevant right now)

The function `tex.hashtokens` returns a table which contains only the entries of the "normal" hash table and *not* the `hash_extra` part. So in some sense it lists the control sequence names which can be accessed particularly fast, not all of them. I don't know if this behavior is intentional, but I personally think that returning all names would be more useful. In any case, as ShreevatsaR mentioned you can force `tex.hashtokens` to return all names in a particular run by running LuaTeX as `hash_extra=0 lualatex foo.tex` and therefore forcing the `hash_extra` part to be empty. In this case, you can't use more than 65536 different control sequences though.

Comment: On my machine the limit is `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [hash size=71689].`...? (side note the command-line above only works in bash/similar shells, it won't work on Windows cmd, and I think it's possible to set hash_extra in texmf.cnf as well)