# How to display a list of all user made newcommands and what they do?

Tags: renewcommand

I am writing my bachelor thesis and I am introducing more and more newcommands, but I tend to forget them. Is there a way to display all user created new commands, like a make a list or a table?
I could make a table myself, but I would have to update it every time I add more commands.
Weirdly enough I could find nothing online about this.
Thank you all in advance

Comment: tex does not keep track of definitions made, you need to do this yourself

Comment: ther are package such as glossaries and acronyms that help make specific lists of certain types of command

Comment: Alternatively, put all of your `\newcommand`’s in the same file, and format the file nicely so that it is easy to get an overview and look up definitions.

Comment: It's semi-possible but not recommended for typical users [luatex - tex.hashtokens incomplete? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574607/tex-hashtokens-incomplete)

Comment: If you tend to forget about your new macros, maybe they aren't necessary? I'd only make a new macro for things needed frequently.

Comment: @user202729  I wasn't going to mention that:-)

Comment: you could define a `\trackmycommand{commandname}` command and use it together with your `\newcommand`.